# Excel > IFNA lookup, how do I return the original value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 365 Query,

I am trying to produce a Employee to Staff record number comparison. I have figured out using `IFNA` how to make it say 'Not found' but I am wanting to know if it'd be possible to say 'Not found (original value).

So if Employee was #2 and the staff number was #3 then it would say 'Not found #2' as the staff number should also show as 2, if that makes sense

[image]

Currently, I am using code which looks like:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3,C:C,1,FALSE),"Not found")
```

Thanks
J.

Comment: Do you mean: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3,C:C,1,FALSE),"Not found #"&A3)`?

Comment: Or, do you simply want to compare `A2` to `C2`, `A3` to `C3` etc. as per your comment: *"So if Employee was #2 and the staff number was #3 then it would say 'Not found #2'"*: `IF(A2<>C2,"Not found "&A2,A2)`

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, you can build dynamic text strings using &. If you have static text, in your example, this would be Not Found, you would place that in "" and the use & followed by a reference to the cell where the value is held. It would look something like;

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3,C:C,1,FALSE),"Not found #"&A3)
```

Anything within "" is treated as text and the & appends the value in A3.